# Connecting two AWS VPCs in different regions

Tags: amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

I have 2 VPC's in different regions (Virginia and Ohio)

They both have IP ranges of:

172.31.0.0/16

1. Do I need to change the IP ranges of one region? How would I do that if I already have servers associated with this VPC? What IP range would you suggest for Ohio Region?
2. When I setup VPC peering this will let me connect the two regions together using private addresses? Can I use RDS addresses also between regions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have separate networks with overlapping addresses.  You may have to delete and recreate the VPC (use Cloud Formation to rebuild an exact copy).

Comment: Ok and what should I use for my IP address range? I was thinking 10.31.0.0/16 to be similar to other region.

Comment: You can use any private address range that makes sense to you.

Comment: So there is NOT a way to modify an existing VPC to have new IP addresses? It also seems I have to create images of servers to put them in a new VPC. I am trying to have as little steps as possible. My end goal is to make my two regions able to connect to each other just like they are in same network.

Comment: I don't know of a way, but maybe someone else does.  You've made an inadvertent but fundamental error when you gave them the same address space.

Comment: Is there any other way to allow RDS connections in Ohio Region coming from Virginia Region. I know one way would be to add all the public ip addresses; but that is error prone. I can rebuild my Ohio Region if needed but that would be last resort. I am doing cross region replication from virgina to ohio using their built on GUI; so something must be possible. (I want to do it manually as I am going to replicate from Aurora to a mysql database)